# Parsing a stream of JSON with pipes-aeson

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Given a simple example JSON type:

```
data Test = Test
  { name :: Text
  , age  :: Int
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Test
```

How can I use pipes-aeson to decode a stream of JSON messages coming over a socket using the `decoded` lens? As an example I'd like to just print them out as they're parsed:

```
main = connect "127.0.0.1" "8000" $ \(socket, _) -> $ runEffect $
  some use of zoom decoded? view decoded? >-> P.print
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`decoded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-aeson-0.4.1.2/docs/Pipes-Aeson-Unchecked.html#v:decoded) (the one from `Pipes.Aeson.Unchecked`) is a lens than transforms a Producer of raw bytes into a Producer of parsed `FromJSON` values.

So, we must first create the Producer of bytes out of the socket using the [`fromSocket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-network-0.6.4/docs/Pipes-Network-TCP.html#v:fromSocket) function from the `pipes-network` package. Something like this:

```
-- to help with type inference
printTest :: (MonadIO m) => Consumer' Test m r
printTest = P.print

main = do
    connect "127.0.0.1" "8000" $ \(socket, _) -> $ runEffect $
        view decoded (fromSocket socket 4096) >-> printTest
    return ()
```

Comment: That should be `fromSocket socket 4096`?